# MYSQL fulltext match not returning the expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I created a MYSQL table using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`name`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX(`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And have the following rows:

```
   id | name
   ----------
    1 | Acer Liquid Z6 Plus
    2 | Acer Liquid Z6
    3 | Acer Liquid X2
```

I want to to use the `MATCH` query to search for `Acer Liquid Z6` so I ran the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('acer liquid z6' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

The query for some reason returns `Acer Liquid Z6 Plus` as the first result:

```
   id | name
   ----------
    1 | Acer Liquid Z6 Plus
    2 | Acer Liquid Z6
    3 | Acer Liquid X2
```

So the fulltext index is not returning the most relevant result first. Is there a more reliable way to search the index or force the match to return the most relevant result first?

Comment: For what it's worth, MySQL's FULLTEXT search performs strangely on small test datasets. It also, by default, ignores "words" shorter than three characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL builds the full text index, it does not index all words.  There are multiple different parameters -- what defines a word boundary, what characters are allowed in a word.  And the two most important:

- Minimum word length
- Stop words list

The minimum word length is 3 or 4, depending on the storage engine.  In either case, `'z6'` would be ignored. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length) is good place to start in understanding these parameters.

You will need to set the parameter to an appropriate value and rebuild the index.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue. Fulltext search match the words against the columns you have given, since the first row matches the words it gets added to the result list or array. Had your data stored like this

id | name

---

```
1 | Acer Liquid Z6
2 | Acer Liquid Z6 Plus
3 | Acer Liquid X2
```

Then the first row returned would be Acer Liquid Z6.

Furthermore, you can play with minimum word length to have your satisfaction achieved. But, I don't see the problem. You could always filter the list with backend code.

Comment: "Had your data stored like this" that's actually the problem, the data is not sorted in the way guaranteed to return the expected result first. The problem is that this is a URL parameter and I want to match this parameter with the correct record from the database, not an actual search. It has to be like an id for the row but without actually being an ID. It seems modifying the minimum word length would solve it  but i'm on a shared hosting so my second solution would be to store the URL parameter in the database (if no other solution)